# How to plot a complex function in Domain coloring/color wheel graph?

Tags: plot

[image]

That's what I want to plot in LaTeX. I'm gonna have Complex Analysis, and I want to be able to plot complex functions like this when I'm going to create my own notes in LaTeX

How should I do this? I am unable to find any information on that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Like how? It is about a specific problem: I want to plot complex functions by Domain coloring in LaTeX, but I can't find any information on how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I'm unlikely to be able to help, but could you edit your question to give us your specific functions to play with?

Comment: It's not about a specific function. But if you want to have one to play with, let's go with $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\left(x-2-i\right)^2}{x^2+2+2i}$ as it's the function which is visualized by that color wheel graph I've put here as an example